# Ruby version for Multithreading

Tags: ruby

I have to parallel my ruby script and till now I was programming in 2.2.0. The cluster where the script will run has a Ruby version of 1.8.7. Which version is more suitable for multithreading? Is there a difference in 2.2.0 and 1.8.7 concerning multithreading?

Comment: Though both versions of Ruby have no 'real' multithreading, Ruby 2.2.0 is very significantly different from 1.8.7 in terms of API and language features. If you're going to deploy to 1.8.7, you should test locally on that version, too. Also, [Ruby 1.8.7 is already end-of-lifed](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/).

Comment: If your script will run on a cluster, then your processing power is cheap, go simple, take the easy road, make beautiful and processing expensive scripts, run one thousand process instead of one thousand threads, don't use threads, they're hard to maintain. The following link emphasizes my point, check it out: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/09/23.html _The Duct Tape Programmer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference between Ruby versions. There *is*, however, a difference between different Ruby implementations, or even different versions of the same implementation.

- MRI: green threads, can only run one Ruby thread at a time, but can have multiple C threads (e.g. started by C extensions), and multiple Ruby threads can wait for I/O (note that MRI is obsolete, no longer maintained, and abandoned)
- YARV: native threads, but Giant VM Lock prevents two threads from entering the bytecode interpreter loop at the same time, so cannot run Ruby code in parallel, but multiple threads can run C code in parallel
- Rubinius: native threads, can run in parallel
- (very) old Rubinius: green threads, can't run in parallel
- JRuby: native threads (where "native" means "JVM"), can run in parallel, if JVM supports it (most do)
- IronRuby: native threads (where "native" means "CLI VES"), can run in parallel, if VES supports it (all of them do)
- MagLev: not sure
- MacRuby: native threads, can run in parallel
- MRuby: not sure
- RubyMotion: not sure

In particular, broken code that *appears* to work on MRI and YARV may crash, fail, break, or behave unexpectedly on JRuby, IronRuby, MacRuby and Rubinius.

Comment: I am quite new to multithreading and my problem is that I have 20 huge which I have to open and perform searching there. So my idea was to create 4 threads , so that each will open 5 files and perform searching to reduce the runinng time (in comparison to subsequently open 20 files). As I understood you, my only option would be MacRuby or Rubinius

Comment: Or JRuby. Or use 4 processes instead of threads. Or, depending on what you mean by "searching", the code would be implemented in C and run in parallel even on YARV and MRI. Or, you are mostly doing I/O, which is asynchronous and concurrent even on MRI and YARV.

Comment: Basically, the files (A,B,C...) contains intervals and some values specific or those intervals. I have an input file with the intervals and the name of the file (A,B,C...) to open. I open the needed file and search for the needed intervals and do operations with the values specific for those intervals, if the calculated value is above threshold I stop and save if not I go further to another interval. Another idea is to divide and input file into 4 sections, so that every process/thread with deal with its section but it might happen that two threads/processes will have to open the same file.